# infinte scroll with loading msg after 10 items

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am displaying a list of items. I want, when we scroll, after displaying 10 items. it displays " loading more..."

```
(ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)"
```

is not triggering.

**.html file**

```
<ion-content padding>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let i of items">{{i}}</ion-item>
  </ion-list>

  <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingSpinner="bubbles" loadingText="Loading more data...">
    </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>

</ion-content>
```

**.ts file**

```
import { IonInfiniteScroll, IonVirtualScroll } from '@ionic/angular';

export class FoodMenuPage implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(IonInfiniteScroll) infiniteScroll: IonInfiniteScroll;
  items = [];

  constructor() { 
    for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
      this.items.push( this.items.length );
      }
  }


  doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
    console.log('Begin async operation');

    setTimeout(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    this.items.push( this.items.length );
    }

    console.log('Async operation has ended');
    infiniteScroll.complete();
    }, 500);
    }
```

Comment: some one plz...help me...provide me the solution

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
<ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingSpinner="bubbles" loadingText="Loading more data...">
</ion-infinite-scroll-content>
```

```
<div *ngIf="pagingEnabled" class="nomore_data"> No more data is available.</div>
```

**TS**

```
if (this.image1 != 0) {
        for (let i in this.image1) {
          this.images = this.images.concat(this.image1[i]);
        }
      } else {
        this.pagingEnabled = true;
      } \\image1 and image have same json value

if (Infinitescroll) { \\every scroll infinite has been fire
        Infinitescroll.target.complete();\\every scroll tarhas been completed
      }
```

no need for viewchild or anything

Comment: I am not using any image

Comment: image is an array.u can change ur array value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196352/discussion-between-naveen-pandi-and-annaya).